# Вывести каждый елемент массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Вывести каждый елемент массива у которого соседний с права элемент - парный

такой код

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] %2 === 0){
            console.log(arr);
        }

}
```

что не так ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас две ошибки: вы проверяете сам элемент, а не его соседа справа, и выводите не элемент, а массив целиком. Попробуйте так:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i + 1] % 2 === 0){
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: если нужно слева тогда i - 1